# CSS3 Border Images

Tags: gradient, css

I'm trying to achieve a 5px gradient around all edges. I've found multiple ways to do this in all browsers except for IE (-mos-border-colors and apply 5 separate colors, border-image, etc...).

I've tried CSS3 Pie, but can't seem to get it to function at all in IE (any version). There are multiple sizes for this column, so images would be a hassle.

Any one have any solutions for this?

```
    .col {
        border: 5px solid;
        -moz-border-image: url(../images/bg-border.png) 5 5 5 5 stretch;
        -webkit-border-image: url(../images/bg-border.png) 5 5 5 5 stretch;
        border-image: url(../images/bg-border.png) 5 5 5 5 stretch;
        behavior: url(/htc/Support/assets/css/PIE.htc);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `box-shadow` is an option for you, enabling monochrome gradients/shades…

```
header {
    box-shadow: 0 1em 2em #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1em 2em #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1em 2em #fff; }
```

[Does it really need to look identical in every browser?](http://boagworld.com/design/where-are-my-rounded-corners/)

Comment: It is best to put the CSS3 standards after the browser specific statements. `box-shadow` should be last.

Comment: @js1568 Is there any reason for that tip?

Comment: For future browsers that support more than one line of the above code, it is better to have the standards in effect override the proprietary.

Comment: I'd like it to look similar. If CSS Pie supported box-shadow inset, I'd be done by now. I'm essentially just trying to create a div with a beveled edge.

Answer (score 0):

Some cross browser solutions: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient

> Please note not all browsers support CSS gradient. To be safe, you shouldn't rely on CSS gradient when coding the layout. It should only be used for enhancing the layout.

Comment: this isn't really useful for borders, except you have one element for each border (N,E,S,W)

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried CSS3 Pie, but can't seem to get it to function at all in IE
>   (any version).

CSS3-Pie is a bit tricky. Try adding `position:relative;` to the element you want to apply border image to.

Comment: I added position relative, and it still seems to disregard the image completely and fill the border with a dark gray. I snooped around, and some one mentioned to add "border-color: transparent", which just made the border disappear in IE.

Any other thoughts on why this wouldn't work in IE?

Answer (score 0):

csspie cannot resolve relative paths from your stylesheet to your images.  If you do not specify absolute paths from document root to your images, css pie cannot find them.

See this issue here:
http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths